# Python shift() from same column like in Excel

Tags: python

I want to create this table in python:

```
x1  target
1   1
1   1
23  2
32  3
1   1
2   2
2   3
4   4
1   1
```

This is easy to solve in Excel,
[image]

but I don't know, how can I do this in pyton:
First target row is "1", then:

```
target = if ['x1']=1 then ['target']=1 else ['target']=['target'].shift(1)+1
```

I tried this code, but doesn't worked:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('/x1.xlsx')
df.loc[df.index == 0, 'target'] = 1
df.loc[df['x1']==1, 'target'] = 1
df.loc[df['x1'] != 1, 'target'] = df['target'].shift(1)+1
```

Anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: x1: [1,1,23,32,1,2,2,4,1]
target: [1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1]

Comment: Yes, you can do shift(1) or shift(-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get groups with `cumsum` and number with `cumcount`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 23, 3: 32, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 1}})
df['target'] = df.groupby(df['x1'].eq(1).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
```

Output

```
   x1  target
0   1       1
1   1       1
2  23       2
3  32       3
4   1       1
5   2       2
6   2       3
7   4       4
8   1       1
```

It can be easier to look at the groupby part separately. It creates a number to group on, where every time `x1` is equal to 1 the number increases.  Once we group on this, we can take the cumulative count of the number of records in the group and add 1 to account for starting at zero.

```
df['x1'].eq(1).cumsum()

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! This solution is work perfectly, but my rally problem is more complicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788112/python-shift-from-same-column-like-in-excel-with-dates
Could you help me please?